# SQL statement to create a boolean column that is based on a foreign table's boolean column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables with hierarchical data like this:

categories->feeds->channels where feeds has FK category_id and channels has FK feed_id.

channels has a boolean value, subscribed.  I want to select all the categories and create a subscribed (boolean) column that is '1' if any channel in any of its feeds is '1'.  I am using SQLite.

First I tried this:

```
SELECT categories.category_id, categories.title,
    CASE when (channels.subscribed = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS subscribed
FROM categories
    JOIN feeds ON categories.category_id = feeds.category_id
    JOIN channels ON feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id;
```

this gave me all the categories for every channel in the database, with categories.subscribed = 1 if channels.subscribed = 1.  However, I just want each category once in the result set, with categories.subscribed being 1 if any of the channels are subscribed.  So I tried to use group by:

```
SELECT categories.category_id, categories.title,
    CASE when (channels.subscribed = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS subscribed
FROM categories
    JOIN feeds ON categories.category_id = feeds.category_id
    JOIN channels ON feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id;
GROUP BY categories.category_id;
```

this gave me the result set I wanted but the subscribed column was not correct, predictably:

```
id|title|subscribed
38|cat1|0
19|cat2|0
```

whereas I want this:

```
38|cat1|0
19|cat2|1
```

because in cat2 there is a feed that contains a channel that is subscribed.  Is there a function that I can use or perhaps a more complex CASE statement that I have to make to get this to work?  Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I according to this post:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/07/11/1744.aspx

I can use the "aggregate boolean OR" function, which is just a MAX() on the subscribed column, to get what I want, which is what I had in mind, I just couldn't put it into SQL.  So what works for me is this:

```
SELECT categories.category_id, categories.title,
    MAX(CASE when (channels.subscribed = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS subscribed
FROM categories
    JOIN feeds ON categories.category_id = feeds.category_id
    JOIN channels ON feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id;
GROUP BY categories.category_id;
```

If anyone has a better answer please post it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT categories.category_id, categories.title,
(select count(distinct channels.subscribed) 
 from feeds, channels
 where categories.category_id = feeds.category_id
   and feeds.feed_id = channels.feed_id
   and channels.subscribed = 1)
FROM categories
```

Comment: this produces the correct output, but so does mine.  Is this better than my answer?  "better" as in, this is being performed on the android platform, so I guess memory usage or overall efficiency?  what do you think?  Another problem is I have to translate this into a ContentProvider and straight joins are easier than subselections...